# Is there a way to combine two lists in Python for searching?

Tags: python, string, list

I could not think of a way to title the question but I can explain. Let's say the user has to input one string containing two words. There are, however, multiple ways to write each one of those words. So something like:

```py
words = input("Enter 'Hello World' however you want to type it ")
possibilities = [
    "Hello World",
    "hello World",
    "Hello world",
    "hello world",
    "Helo World",
    "helo World",
    "Helo world",
    "helo world"
]
if words in possibilities:
    print("true")
```

##### Note:

I know that this specific example could be solved by just typing words.lower() and that you that helo would be a serious typo, it's just an example.

---

Is there any way to do it like this?

```py
words = input("Enter 'Hello World' however you want to type it ")
firstWord = [
    "Hello",
    "hello",
    "Helo",
    "helo"
]
secondWord = [
    "World",
    "world",
]
words = words.split(' ')
if words[0] in firstWord and words[1] in secondWord:
    print("true")
```

Comment: The process you're trying to achieve is called "fuzzy string matching", and is deceptively complex.

Comment: Look for some distance metric (hamming, levenshtein, etc.) and set a threshold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

See https://tedboy.github.io/nlps/generated/generated/nltk.edit_distance.html#nltk-edit-distance as an example for a python library that will calculate the distance between "Hello" and "helo"

Answer (score 2):

Answering the question as asked, you can use `itertools.product` to produce all the combinations of the two lists.

```
from itertools import product


if words in [' '.join(t) for t in product(firstWord, secondWord)]:
    print("true")
```

This can be extended:

```
parts = [["h", "H"], ["ello", "elo"], [" "], ["W", "w"], ["orld"]]
if words in [''.join(t) for t in product(*parts)]:
    print("true")
```